# angularjs ng-false-value set to nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a checkbox in angular like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,option) in metaItem.fieldOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="metaField[]"
           ng-model="issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]"
           ng-true-value="'{{option.optionValue}}'" 
           ng-false-value="'{{null}}'">     
           {{option.optionPlaceholder}}
</div>
```

So `ng-model`, `issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]` is initially empty, its like this:

```
{}
```

Say I click option of supplier, I get this:

```
{"0":"Supplier"}
```

Then, If I deselect, I get this:

```
{"0":""}
```

What I want upon deselect is this:

```
{}
```

This is to keep it inline with code I am replacing. Any suggestions?

Comment: _The object is initially empty_ - which object? You don't need `'{{`.

Comment: what is `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`? You should just be using `ng-model`

Comment: When I say object is initally empty, I meant `ng-model`, `issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]`, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2 - Revised answer based on comments:**

From comments, I understand that the object model you have is along the following lines:

```
metaItem.fieldOptions = 
  {0: {optionValue: "Supplier"}, 
   1: {optionValue: "SomethingA"}, 
   2: {optionValue: "SomethingB"}};
```

And you want the selected values to populate the `fieldValue` object. So, say, for selected keys `0` and `2`, the following appears:

```
issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue = {0: "Supplier", 2: "SomethingB"};
```

and the problem is if you deselect `0`, you get this:

```
issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue = {0: "", 2: "SomethingB"};
```

But you want this:

```
issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue = {2: "SomethingB"};
```

**Answer:** 
This is easily solved if you assigned `undefined` in `ng-false-value`:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]" 
       ng-true-value="'{{option.optionValue}}'" ng-false-value="undefined">
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hPn01mcxjzoHGSwMZQrW?p=preview)

====

**Original answer:**

Simply put, you want the model set in `ng-model` to be `"some string"` if `true`, and empty object `{}` - if `false`, right?

Then, just set these as the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="foo" ng-true-value="'some string'" ng-false-value="{}">
```

To apply it directly to your example,

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,option) in metaItem.fieldOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           ng-model="issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]"
           ng-true-value="'{{option.optionValue}}'" 
           ng-false-value="{}">     
           {{option.optionPlaceholder}}
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

If, instead of `"some string"`, you want to set your model to an object, you could supply an object literal hardcoded inline:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="foo" ng-true-value="{0: 'Supplier'}" ng-false-value="{}">
```

In your example, where this object is set dynamically within `ng-repeat`'s iteration, then it's better if you have that object literal prepared.

Say, you had `option.optionValue === {0: "Supplier"}` for this iteration (doesn't look like you do, but that would be the right approach, since the object is, in fact, an "option value"), then you could set it like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]" 
       ng-true-value="{{option.optionValue}}" ng-false-value="{}">
```

If you don't have it prepared and you need to construct it "on the fly", you could use `ng-init` for that. Say, the `"0"` in your example comes from `option.optionKey`, and `"Supplier"` comes from `option.optionValue`:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-init="t = {}; t[option.optionKey] = option.optionValue"
       ng-model="issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]" 
       ng-true-value="{{t}}" ng-false-value="{}">
```

Comment: So if I choose supplier, `ng-model`= `{"0":"Supplier"}`, then click off, with this technique I get  `ng-model`=`{"0":{}}`. What I want when I click off is  `ng-model`=`{}`.

Comment: I am currently stripping the empty/false values out in the controller, but it would be nice to have it all figured out by that time.

Comment: @Octopi, where is this object `{0: "Supplier"}` coming from? Anyway - I edited the question with variations, but please, next time provide this kind of relevant information in the question

Comment: Apologies, `{0: "Supplier"}` is the ng-model, so checkbox `0` with true value of `Supplier`. so `issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[0]` = `Supplier`

Comment: @Octopi, ok, I think I understand you object model, and revised the answer (see the top part). Please, next time, make this object model clear in the question to avoid this back-and-forth

Comment: I have another question on this if you want to get in on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006996/angularjs-apostrophe-in-checkbox-ng-true-value

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `required` tag. 
The key value will not appear in the form object unless it is valid.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,option) in metaItem.fieldOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="metaField[]"
           required=""
           ng-model="issueForView.metaData[subIndex].fieldValue[key]"
           ng-true-value="'{{option.optionValue}}'" 
           ng-false-value="'{{null}}'">     
           {{option.optionPlaceholder}}
</div>
```