# Passing dynamic value with single quote as a ng-true-value expression fails

Tags: angularjs

I have my checkbox input that sets the "true" value dynamically based on a variable `trueVal`, which is a string.

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-true-value="'{{trueVal}}'">
```

For example, for `trueVal = "something"`, `foo === "something"` when the checkbox is checked.

This works except in the case when `trueVal` equals to a string with a single quote in it: `Customer didn't understand`. In this case, there is an error:

> Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 27-28 ['] in expression ['Customer didn't understand'].

I can't strip the single quotes because the string should be set as-is to `foo`.

**Broader context:**

I'm creating a group of checkboxes based on a list of `options` that I get from the back-end:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,option) in options">
  <input type="checkbox" 
         ng-model="foo[key]"
         ng-true-value="'{{option.trueVal}}'"
         ng-false-value="null">
</div>
```

So, given:

```
options =  {
             0: {trueVal: "Customer was late"},
             1: {trueVal: "Customer didn't understand"}
           };
```

I expect to see:

```
foo = {
  1: "Customer didn't understand"
};
```

if the second box is checked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The short version**, `ng-true-val` expects a constant and is being passed the following expression as a parameter: `'Customer didn't understand'` for evaluation, which is malformed because of un-terminated single quote.

The simple (but somewhat ugly) approach would be to replace `'` with `\'` in the View (this doesn't change the actual value - just encodes it):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo"
       ng-true-value="'{{trueVal.replace('\'', '\\\'')}}'"
       ng-false-value="null">
```

The better approach is probably using `ng-change`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="t"
       ng-change="foo = t ? trueVal : null">
```

**Longer version**

Under the covers `ng-true-value` calls `$parse` service: `var parseFn = $parse(expression)`, and expects `parseFn.constant === true`. The latter is only true if the expression is a constant:

```
expression = 'string';      // string literal
expression = '5'            // number literal
expression = {v: 'string'}  // object literal with a constant
expression = 'foo' + 'bar'; // expression that evaluates to a constant
```

In your case you need to take the variable `trueVal`, interpolate it to a value `{{trueVal}}`, to become part of an expression `'{{trueVal}}'` that ultimately will be evaluated as explained above.

This is why substitution of `'` works to `\'`, because it escapes the singles quotes as if you have written the expression directly:

```
ng-true-value="'Customer didn\'t understand'"
```

If you are certain that you won't have double quotes (`"`) in your values for `options`, you could also simply reverse the order of quotes without the need to do `replace`:

```
ng-true-value='"{{trueVal}}"`
```

This will, of course, fail for the same reason if `trueVal` value had double quotes: `something with "quotes"`.

Comment: Thanks so much once again for the comprehensive edit and answer. I've taken the first approach. Also, I wish I could absorb your power.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**In Markup**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="dummyModel" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}">
```

**In Controller**

```
var trueValue = "my true' value";
var falseValue = false;
var _model;
$scope.dummyModel = function (val) {
    if (angular.isDefined(val)) {
        _model = val ? trueValue : falseValue
    }
    return _model === trueValue;
}
```

Use `_model` to submit to the database.